# NodeJS request post is slower than direct postman request

Tags: node.js, post, request

I have some problems doing a POST request using nodejs.

This is the code I have:

> ```
> console.time("before");
> const request = require('request');
> const xmlrequest = 'xmlcode...';
> console.timeEnd("before");
> console.time('call');
> request.post('http://serverip', {
>         body: xmlrequest
>     }, (err, response) => {
>         if (err) {
>     }
>     else {
>         console.timeEnd('call');
>     }
> });
> ```

I can do this call 100 times with Postman and 100 times with nodejs and results will always be the same, nodejs taking almost twice as postman. And this is the only code right now in the .js file as I wanted to test it with a clean code.

"before" reports 360ms and that is ok, is the time it takes to load the module, but "call" reports 700 ms.

However if I do the same exact call with Postman it takes 360ms.

I understand that Postman is using a lower level call to the system API and nodejs might be using a higher level call but I would like to see if there is any way to make this same call faster.

I tried also with fetch with no improvements.

Comment: Are you comparing single requests or are these averages  of large samples? A sample size of 1 may not be enough to compare them side by side

Comment: I'm comparing a lot of different requests, however in this instance, I just wrote a request.post in nodejs and takes 700ms doing the same request I'm doing in postman and taking 360ms so I was wondering if is the request.post slower than whatever postman uses.